# Managing Joomla Website

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, cvs

Currently my workflow is like this:

1. Make some changes to the local
   copy of my website
2. Use Akeeba backup to make a copy of my website and database
3. Delete contents of hosted server
4. Upload Akeeba backup files
5. Visit website and
   run akeeba restore which syncs my
   database

Is there a better way to manage a joomla website?  The problem is, I have a team working on one website so this doesn't really work as well.  Setting up version control with the server won't exactly work because pretty much everything in Joomla gets stored in a database so we would need to somehow also get the CVS to work with the database.  Potentially if Joomla and SQLite worked together (they don't) a CVS solution might work.

Comment: What kind of changes are you making and how often are you making them?

Comment: Finding new plugins, implementing new features, we're making changes daily.

Answer (score 0):

Write a php script, doesn't look like you are doing anything to difficult.

Comment: A php script that does what? Implements version control and automatically keeps a database synced?  Sounds difficult

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see with your process is the downtime. In order to eliminate the downtime you can create two versions of Joomla on your LIVE server and point the apache to one of them, when you deploy your code, do it to the currently "off-line" version of Joomla and after you finish the deploy - point the apache to that version. Just a thought ;)